# Drone Repo Add throwing error - No help topic for 'add'

Tags: drone.io

Getting the following error when using drone cli to add/activate repo

> No help topic for 'add'

I can confirm I am successfully login and I am an admin.

```
{"id":1,"login":"XXXXX","email":"","machine":false,"admin":true,"active":true,"avatar":"https://bitbucket.org/account/XXXX/avatar/32/","syncing":false,"synced":1578888217,"created":1578431775,"updated":1578891320,"last_login":1578891344}
```

I can also list my repo using '**drone repo ls**'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess, if you are using the `add` option is that you are still interacting with drone 0.8 or below, in this case the docs have been archived to an alternate location in favor of the latest version (v1.x).  The old docs are still available under the following URL and help for the `add` option is present there:

- https://0-8-0.docs.drone.io/cli-repository-add/

If you are not using 0.8 and are indeed trying to use 1.x, perhaps you are referencing improper documentation, as this cli option shifted in v1 to `enable`

```
$ drone repo enable <repo/name>
```

Regardless of the versions however, you will want to ensure you both have admin access to the repository (so that drone is able to add the appropriate webhooks) and also refresh or `sync` your repo listing in if it is something brand new:

```
$ drone repo sync
username/hello-world
organization/minio
...
```

**NOTE**: This might take a bit depending on how many repos you have access to

Comment: Thanks @hikerspath, I had to add the bitbucket user as drone admin as well. 
`  --env=DRONE_BITBUCKET_CLIENT_ID=client-id-here \
  --env=DRONE_BITBUCKET_CLIENT_SECRET=secret-here \
--env=DRONE_USER_CREATE=username:myusername,machine:false,admin:true,token:my-123-token \`